# Parse deploy code not working

Tags: ios, json, parse-platform, command-line-interface, web-deployment

Trying to do a parse deploy of this project.
https://github.com/HubSpot/BidHub-CloudCode
But keep getting this error
[image]

already added application id

this is my global.json file

```
{
    "applications": {
        "BidHub": {
            "applicationId": "XXXXXXXX",
            "masterKey": "XXXXXXXX"
        }, 
        "_default": {
            "link": ""
        }
    }, 
    "global": {
        "parseVersion": "1.3.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the configuration files have changed since this app last updated. I would suggest you to create a new Parse app using `parse new` command. Then copy the scripts in the cloud folder to your new app's cloud folder.

Comment: still doesnt seem to work, does it work for u?

Comment: @knshn You are partially right..

Comment: and which part was not right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as what knshn suggested create a new Parse app and copy the JS script or use existing. Please refer to https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#command-line

Answer (score 0):

Ok, even after updating to new tools this did not work. So I had to use windows parse CLI to get this done, which was done smoothly.